# Dropbox SDK for android is not working, NoClassDefFoundError is coming

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have tried to run ["Hello Dropbox Example"](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/android)

**Dropbox SDK Version 3.1.1, updated October 10, 2014**

and put

armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86, dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar

FOLDER TO LIBS FOLDER

also done

PROJECT PROPERTIS -> JavaBuild Path- > Add jar - > dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar

also done

PROJECT PROPERTIS -> JavaBuild Path- > Order and Export -> TICK MARK On dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar

But getting error while run

```
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199): Process: com.dropbox.sample.hellodropbox, PID: 5199
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at com.dropbox.sample.hellodropbox.HelloDropboxActivity.onCreate(HelloDropboxActivity.java:44)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-17 17:08:20.112: E/AndroidRuntime(5199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the Complete "Lib/" folder from  "dropbox-android-sync-sdk"

Comment: There is no "Lib/" folder in "dropbox-android-sync-sdk"

Comment: Add the Complete "libs/***" https://www.dropbox.com/developers/downloads/sdks/sync/android/dropbox-android-sync-sdk-3.1.1.zip